# Removing Associations doctrine symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two relationships.
**product family**.

a family can have several products. a product belongs to one family.

Taking a product like you can remove the family relationship. ie how could leave a product without family?

I tried this:

```
$product->getFamily()->remove();
$product->setFamily(null);
```

but not working.
must be an instance of my\myBundle\Entity\Family
 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use the annotation "nullable=true" like in this way:

```
class Product
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Family", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="family_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $family;
```

And thus, I think that you could set the null value to the family attribute like in your example:

```
$product->setFamily(null);
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Have you run the "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" after doing this? If this doesn't work, paste the whole code of your class for trying to view what is wrong.